# Format STR_TO_DATE to a date

Tags: php, mysql, string, date

Hi I have been able to extract a `VARCHAR` to a date using `string_to_date`, however whatever I try the date always echoes as e.g. `2009-05-25`
Here is my code that works:

```
$query = "SELECT u.url_id, url, title, description, STR_TO_DATE( pub_date, '%d-%b-%Y') 
    AS pub_date FROM urls AS u, url_associations AS ua WHERE u.url_id = ua.url_id AND
    ua.url_category_id=$type AND ua.approved = 'Y' ORDER BY pub_date DESC";
$result = mysql_query ($query);
echo "  <tr>
<td align=\"left\">{$row['pub_date']}</td>
</tr>\n";
```

I have tried `DATE_FORMAT` and similar methods but I either receive `2009-05-25` or blank.
Can anyone help me solve this issue. I am looking and testing but I have decided to ask for help here as the assistance is welcomed and those who helped previously were very kind.

Thanks

Sean

Comment: I understand (I think) that you want to output a date in a format other than MySQL's default?  If so, DATE_FORMAT() is the correct function to use.  What format do you want?  Show how you used DATE_FORMAT() that did not give the desired result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The return type of `STR_TO_DATE` is `DATE` which is returned to `PHP`.

It's `PHP` that formats dates in your `echo`, not `MySQL`.

To do the formatting on `MySQL` side, use:

```
DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE( pub_date, '%d-%b-%Y'), '%Y.%m.%d')
```

or other format.

The inner format controls how your string is expected to be stored in the database, the outer format controls how will it be output.

To do the formatting on `PHP` side (which is better as you can honor culture specific formats for different users), use:

```
echo date('Y m d', strtotime($row['pub_date']))
```

Comment: Thank you so much Quassnoi, the date now shows correctly.
I will add the code so that other's can see how your advice fits in.
Thank you again, I am really grateful to you.  Sean

Comment: I have tried "Answering Your Question" to my questions, but no joy. If anyone would like to have an answer to this - my date picker is jason's js calendar, please email at sean@mediamice.net . Thank you Annath and Zombat, without your initial guidance I wouldn't have a path to follow.
The person who added the missing piece to the puzzle and deserves credit for the solution but not the journey, is Quassnoi. Your input has been both invaluable and warm. results can be seen here - http://mediamice.net/STR_TO_DATE/html/index.php  links are ADD A NEWS FEED & VIEW ALL NEWS FEEDS / CLIENTS.  Thanksx

Answer (score 0):

From [this reference site](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) following are mysql command and output

```
mysql> SELECT DATE_FORMAT('2009-10-04 22:23:00', '%W %M %Y');
        -> 'Sunday October 2009'
mysql> SELECT DATE_FORMAT('2007-10-04 22:23:00', '%H:%i:%s');
        -> '22:23:00'
mysql> SELECT DATE_FORMAT('1900-10-04 22:23:00',
    ->                 '%D %y %a %d %m %b %j');
        -> '4th 00 Thu 04 10 Oct 277'
mysql> SELECT DATE_FORMAT('1997-10-04 22:23:00',
    ->                 '%H %k %I %r %T %S %w');
        -> '22 22 10 10:23:00 PM 22:23:00 00 6'
mysql> SELECT DATE_FORMAT('1999-01-01', '%X %V');
        -> '1998 52'
mysql> SELECT DATE_FORMAT('2006-06-00', '%d');
        -> '00'
```